# I have an American Express gift card and I need to enter a “Name on Card” to buy something, but it’s a gift card and is unnamed?

Tags: gift-card, online-shopping, american-express

I’m on Etsy and I’m asked the name of the card. I can’t pay without inputting it in. I tried just my name and I’m a minor so I’ve never done this before. There is a user guide with the gift card but it doesn’t explain this.

Comment: Did you register the card? You should be able to use the name used at the registration.

Comment: I was sure we already had an answer to this somewhere, but I can't find the other question...

Comment: If anyone asks this question in 2022, Amazon seems to be charging $1 per transaction for this. So for example, I had to redeem my $50 Amex card for $49 of Amazon balance.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what you put in, the gift card's processor will ignore the name. The name is only checked for actual cards that have a name associated. You can put in "gift card" or your actual name or anything else you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes just enter your name and register your card to your name. Make sure the code is linked to your account

Answer (score 0):

I have been known to give the name "Cash" in such situations. If they ask for a first and a last name, the first name is "Cash" and the last name is "Order."